# Unable to install Pandas on Pycharm, Recieving error

Tags: python, pandas, pip, pycharm, program-entry-point

I am trying to get Pandas to work on my Pycharm environment. I have installed it through the command:

```
pip install pandas
```

But when I run the code in my environment, `import pandas as pd`
I get the error:

> No module named 'pandas'

When I try to install it using the project interpreter in Pycharm, I get the error:

> error occurred when installing package 'pandas'

EDIT:
I didn't state what happens when I look into this error. I click 'Details'. 
Then it says:

> AttributeError: module 'pip' has no attribute 'main'

Perhaps this may tell us something about the issue

Comment: Do you have your project interpreter set to the correct path?

Comment: if you are installing on windows, make sure you navigate to the correct project path, i.e. C:\Users\USER_NAME\PycharmProjects\PROJECT_NAME\venv\Scripts before using pip install

Comment: i do have it set to the correct path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is identical to the one reported here [Module pip has no attribute 'main'](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000168364-Pycharm-Virenv-AttributeError-module-pip-has-no-attribute-main-occured-)

For pip version 10.x and higher you should update Pycharm to 2018.2.

Or simply run pip in a terminal outside of Pycharm

Answer (score 1):

Which Python version are you using? If you are using Python3, then the correct command is `pip3 install pandas`.

Make sure that the `pip` command you are calling refers to the same python that you are running. Try `pip -V` for more information.

Comment: It would also be helpful to run `python --version` to know which version of python you're running!

Comment: i have python 3.5.2

Comment: Then likely you should `pip3` to install.

Answer (score 1):

-Update your pycharm to the latest version
-Update pip to the latest version and ensure its same as the `python.exc`
-Run `pip install pandas` command as an administrator
-Try installing pandas again

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you installed Pandas for python2 by pip. For python3, you need to use pip3.

However, it doesn't matter regarding your problem. Probably, you don't choose the right project interpreter.

For Pycharm, it supports the system python(2 and 3), as well as the virtual environment. You may install the Pandas module in system python, but use the virtual environment as default.

Simple solution

1. Make sure you select the interpreter you want (system or
       virtualenv);
2. Check package list, if there is Pandas module;
3. If yes, refresh the project list;
4. If not, simply click + to search Pandas and install it to your
   project interpreter.

Comment: that  is what i am doing and it gives me an error, 'pip' has no attribute 'main'

Comment: It's a Pycharm BUG "Package management doesn't work with pip 10.0 " [BUG Link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29395). Please recreate the virtual environment from the scratch, it may work. [Solutions at Pycharm support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000168364-Pycharm-Virenv-AttributeError-module-pip-has-no-attribute-main-occured-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually PyCharm installs package from path C:\Users<user-name>\PyCharmProject\pyCharmProject1\venv\bin>pip install pandas
In this path there is python different version. This is happened, because while creating project in PyCharm, it automatically sets wrong version of python. To confirm this run same command manually from that path. So, while creating project, select python version from C://ProgramFiles/Python38/bin.